# Hamburger Menu Only Works On One Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a hamburger menu for my site and everything works properly until after I click a link. After that, it will take me to the new page but clicking the menu will do nothing. Refreshing the page fixes the problem so I tried to add a window.location.reload which works fine in chrome but won't follow links in Safari and Firefox.

This is the code for the menu:

HTML & PHP

```
    <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <div id="nav-icon3">
            <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation column displaynone" id="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item is-active"><a
                href="http://localhost:8888/general-economy">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a
                href="http://localhost:8888/general-economy/search">Search</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a
                href="http://localhost:8888/general-economy/about">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a
                href="http://localhost:8888/general-economy/subscribe">Subscribe</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

CSS

```
#nav-icon1, #nav-icon2, #nav-icon3, #nav-icon4 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100000;
}

#nav-icon1 span, #nav-icon3 span, #nav-icon4 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #FF00BF;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100000;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });

  $('#nav-icon3').click(function() {
    $('#nav').toggleClass('displaynone');
    $('body').toggleClass('only-menu');

   });
});
```

Comment: Can you also paste the resultant HTML generated by PHP?

Comment: Your javascript is missing a closing bracket for document.ready "});"

Comment: Added the HTML resulting from the PHP and added the final brackets in the javascript

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your `toggleClass` is fighting against itself as both functions are fried when you click `#nav-icon3`. The below should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('#nav').toggleClass('displaynone');
        $('body').toggleClass('only-menu');
    })
});
```

Comment: I condensed everything into the one click like this code but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I apologize. I spent forever looking at solutions online and I just found out the issue to be some other javascript libraries I was loading in were conflicting with the code.

Comment: can you delete the post?

Comment: Won't let me as people have invested in commenting on it